# Convert pandas column to datetime with unusual max value

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have a DataFrame read in from a database. It holds dates telling me the validity of a row, unfortunately in a Decimal format (14 digits like this `20190130110429`); also if the entry is still valid (i.e. the date is in the future) the column holds `999999999999999` (15 nines).

When I try to convert it to datetime with

```py
pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
```

it fails for the 999... entries. I tried to consider both cases separately

```py
df['date'] = df['date'].astype(str)
mask = df['date']=='999999999999999'
df.loc[~mask,'date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[~mask,'date'],format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
df.loc[mask,'date'] = pd.datetime.max # also tried np.datetime64(pd.datetime.max,unit='s')
```

But this mixes the types:

```
[(x,type(x)) for x in df['date']

[(datetime.datetime(9999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999), datetime.datetime),
 (1548846269000000000, int),
...
]
```

Any ideas how to nicely handle this?

PS: Just before sending the question, I just solved it by

```
    df['date'] = df['date'].astype(str)
    df['date'] = df['date'].str.replace('999999999999999',pd.Timestamp.max.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
```

This gives me '2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807' as the max date. (How) Is it possible store the datetime64[s] or [us] maximum instead of the datetime64[ns]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.to_datetime` returns a `Timestamp`:

```
pd.to_datetime('20190130110429')
# Timestamp('2019-01-30 11:04:29')
```

This is pandas' native datetime format. OTOH, `pd.datetime` is a different type (`datetime.datetime`). They are different and sometimes not compatible. What you have is a good example of this. Specifically, you'll notice they have different max values.

```
pd.datetime.max
# datetime.datetime(9999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999)
pd.Timestamp.max
# Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')
```

Since the former is not compatible with the latter, the result is an object column (pandas cannot convert it into a scalar `Timestamp` column) and the result is a weird mix of dates and integers.

My suggestion would be `replace` and `fillna`:

```
df['date'] = (
    pd.to_datetime(df['date'].replace('999999999999999', np.nan))
      .fillna(pd.Timestamp.max))
```

Comment: Is it possible to use Timestamp with `s` or `d` resolution?

Comment: @ifly6 With `floor`, yes: `pd.Timestamp.max.floor('s')` or `pd.Timestamp.max.floor('d')`

Comment: But I mean, parsing something like `15APR9999` or `19AUG14`

Comment: @ifly6 you can parse whatever date you like with the appropriate format. See http://strftime.org for a listing of datetime format specifiers.

Comment: I understand that I can parse dates of format `15APR9999` in the same way I can parse dates of the format `9999-04-15`. All of the dates above, from the death of Augustus to near the "end" of time, are outside the Timestamp range. How does one specify the proper resolution to put them back in range?

Comment: @ifly6 If you're trying to make the point that this will not handle arbitrary out of bounds timestamps, then that fix is pretty simple: Add `errors='coerce'` when calling `to_datetime`. Unfortunately, there's nothing to "put them back in range", you'll need to coerce to nans, then fill with a suitable default.

Comment: How would you answer that question in 250 years, i.e. if you have to go beyond pd.Timestamp.max. How can I use the pd.datetime.max or rather have a pandas column of datetime64[s]?

Comment: @WilliamEllisWebb Good question. Maybe in the future where we support 128 bit architectures, or pandas implementation changes to support arbitrary ints (larger than 2 ** 63 - 1, which is how pd.Timestamp is currently implemented).